# Templating engine with higher-order functions - any practical use?

Tags: freemarker, higher-order-functions

I recently ran into Freemarker for generation of pages in our project. The one thing that amazed me very much is that actually Freemarker supports functions as first-class objects, that is, you can use them as arguments passed to other functions in your template.

The question is - what is the practical use for that in HTML page generation, for example. I have written a lot of programs in Common Lisp, Scheme and Haskell in old days, but I don't see how that would work for a practical web application. In our project where are no examples of such usage.

Can anyone point out how can one use Freemarker for web-applications (I mean it's functional part, of course, not it's templating part)?

UPD. I know that Javascript uses that a lot, but that's not the case here - I am talking about templates for HTML generation.

Answer (score 0):

I hope that I understand your question right, but basically what you can do with higher-order-functions in FreeMarker templating is to create macros that take other macros as parameters and use this construct to wrap "inner" items (let's say list items) with an outer HTML structure.

Sure, this can be done by simply putting the wrapper HTML before the <#list> loop, but consider the case you use a certain wrapper HTML for many types of components you render in the frontend, if you want to change something in that global wrapper markup, you have to change it everywhere one-by-one, if you use a higher-order macro that does this, you just have to change the wrapping markup at one place.

This is one example of higher-order FreeMarker functions I can think of. To the question if it has any practical use: I'm not entirely sure =)...in my opinion it makes the templating code overly complicated and unreadable for the sake of maintainability...if one or the other is the goal in a certain project, everyone has to decide from case to case, but I'm sure in one or the other scenario it makes sense to do such things (like the one mentioned in the example above)